# How to make a layering system, with smooth movement (2d RPG)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, paintcomponent

So I'm kind of stuck in a bind. Heres my problem

I can draw a tile, but if I draw a player (which is a JPanel) it covers the other JPanel (that stores the map info)

A way I thought about doing this, is using a layeredPane and creating a grid of JPanels, also to create different layers(so when a unit walks underneath a tree, you can't see them), but I don't know how I could create smooth animation between each square.

I dont know how it would be possible to create smooth movement with a layout manager, but I don't understand layout managers well enough. Once I get this sorted out, I can start working on a map editor.

I am writing this RPG game to better my knowledge of Java, I don't know what code I should provide, so if you want more code I will provide it.

```
//This is a snippet in the player class.
//Objects in here have already been instantiated and loaded, also the class implements
//Action Listener, which calls to repaint the unit.
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 1){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyBackward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairBackward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesBackward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 2){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyBackward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairBackward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesBackward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 3){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyRightway1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairRightway1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesRightway1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 4){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyRightway2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairRightway2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesRightway2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 5){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyForward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairForward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesForward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 6){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyForward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairForward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesForward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 7){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyLeftward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairLeftward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesLeftward1, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }else if(GlobalObjects.playerSpriteImageAlternater == 8){
        g2d.drawImage(unitBodyLeftward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitHairLeftward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        g2d.drawImage(unitClothesLeftward2, GlobalObjects.characterX, GlobalObjects.characterY,32,40, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();  
}
```

Comment: I would render the whole thing to a backing buffer. Maybe using a series of BufferedImages to represent each layer. If a layer hasn't changed, there's no need to update its buffer. I would then simply paint the master buffer within the paintComponent method

Comment: What is a backing buffer?

Comment: Also known as double buffering or page flipping.  The idea is you render the output to an off screen buffer (like a BufferedImage) and once the rendering is complete, you paint it to the screen.  This would involve two or more `BufferedImage`s being flipped from "active" (ready to be painted on the screen) and "inactive" (ready for rendering to).  The idea is, the update process is expensive (from a time point of view), so you want to do it in the background and when it's ready, you flip it to the screen...